# Running binary files

Tags: android

I was able to download a binary file from internet and saved it at my Android device programmatically, the problem is selecting the proper location to be able to execute it, I picked both `app internal` and `data directory` but both gave me:

> Cannot run program "/data/user/0/com.example.dl/app_mounted/server":
> error=13, Permission denied

My code is:
`MainActivity.kt`

```kotlin
package com.example.dl

import android.content.Context
import android.content.ContextWrapper
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import com.example.dl.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.io.*
import java.lang.RuntimeException
import java.net.URL
import java.util.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        val context = this
       val urlFile:URL = URL("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" +
                "1kRtYw3_Yd7he0HjbgNlAAl9we9tQEGvm")

        binding.tvDownload.text = urlFile.toString()
        val tag = "Main Activity"
        val targetFileName = "server"

        val wrapper = ContextWrapper(context)
        /* ******************************** */
        /** What Directory Should I Select **/
        var directory = wrapper.getDir("${Environment.getExternalStorageState()}", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        /* ******************************** */
        var file = File(directory, targetFileName)

        binding.button.setOnClickListener { button ->
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                if (file.exists()) {
                    Log.i(tag, "$file does exist.")
                    // Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/rm /$file")

                    Log.i(tag, "Setting file executable")
                    file?.setExecutable(true)
                    Log.i(tag, "Running executable file")
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(file.toString())

                    //   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh -c $file")

                    binding.tvSaved.text = file.toString()

                    button.isEnabled = true // enable button
                    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                } else {
                    Log.i(tag, "$file does not exist.")
                    binding.tvSaved.text = ""

                button.isEnabled = false // disable button
                binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                // perform these tasks off the main thread
                val savedUri: Uri? = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    // get / download bitmap from url
                    val fileStream: InputStream? = urlFile.toStream(context)
                    Log.i(
                        tag,
                        "Stream $fileStream collected, trying to save it"
                    ) 
                    fileStream?.saveToInternalStorage(context)
                }

                if (savedUri == null) {
                    Log.e(tag, "URI was null. Nothing to save")
                    return@launch
                }

                val execFile = File(savedUri.toString())
                Log.i(tag, "Stream saved")

                Log.i(tag, "Setting file executable")
                execFile?.setExecutable(true)
                Log.i(tag, "Running executable file")
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(savedUri.toString())

                //   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh -c $savedUri")

                // show bitmap saved uri in text view
                binding.tvSaved.text = savedUri.toString()

                button.isEnabled = true // enable button
                binding.progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }

            }
        }
}
```

`Download.kt`

```kotlin
package com.example.dl

import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import java.io.*
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.URL

// extension function to get / download bitmap from url
fun URL.toStream(context : Context): InputStream? {
    return try {
        val tag = "input stream"
            Log.v(tag, "downloadFile() invoked ")
            Log.v(tag, "downloadFile() fileUrl $this")
        //    Log.v(TAG, "downloadFile() directory $directory")
            val url = URL(this.toString())
            val urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            urlConnection.connect()
            val inputStream = urlConnection.inputStream
        inputStream
    } catch (e: IOException){
        null
    }
}
```

`SaveToInternal.kt`

```kotlin
package com.example.dl

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.content.ContextWrapper
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Environment
import android.util.Log
import java.io.*
import java.net.MalformedURLException

// extension function to save an image to internal storage
fun InputStream.saveToInternalStorage(context: Context): Uri?{
    return try {
        val tag = "Saving stream"
        Log.i(tag, "Saving the stream from the web")
        val MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024
        val buffer = ByteArray(MEGABYTE)
        val targetFileName = "server"
        val wrapper = ContextWrapper(context)
         /* ******************************** */
        /** What Directory Should I Select **/
        var directory = wrapper.getDir("${Environment.getExternalStorageState()}", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        /* ******************************** */
        // create a file to save the downloaded one
        var file = File(directory, targetFileName)
        // get the file output stream
        val fileOutputStream: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)

        var bufferLength = 0
        while (this.read(buffer).also { bufferLength = it } > 0) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength)
        }
        fileOutputStream.flush()
        fileOutputStream.close()
        Log.v(tag, "downloadFile() completed ${Uri.parse(file.absolutePath)}")
        Uri.parse(file.absolutePath)
    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "downloadFile() error" + e.message)
        Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "downloadFile() error" + e.stackTrace)
        null
    } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "downloadFile() error" + e.message)
        Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "downloadFile() error" + e.stackTrace)
        null
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "downloadFile() error" + e.message)
        Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "downloadFile() error" + e.stackTrace)
        null
    }
}
```

`layout/activity_main.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EDEAE0"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:viewBindingIgnore="false">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#7BB661"
        android:text="Download Image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDownload"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDownload"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Download URL"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle2"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSaved"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        tools:text="Saved Uri"
        android:padding="8dp"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dl">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Dl">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

`build.gradle (Module)`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dl"
        minSdkVersion 30
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        viewBinding true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0'
    // kotlin coroutine
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.8'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.8'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

**UPDATE**
I saw the below as sample of using `jniLibs` libraries for `calling native lib` how can I do with `executing native binary` whre I do not have the source code

```kotlin
package com.example.dl

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

open class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("native-lib")
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        // Example of a call to a native method
        val tv: TextView = findViewById(R.id.tvDownload)
        tv.text = stringFromJNI()
    }

    /**
     * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
     * which is packaged with this application.
     */
    private external fun stringFromJNI(): String?
}
```

The `*.so` files had been pushed with respective platform (arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64) folder: `app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/native-lib.so`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not supported on modern versions of Android, for security reasons. Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10#execute-permission):

> Untrusted apps that target Android 10 cannot invoke exec() on files within the app's home directory. This execution of files from the writable app home directory is a [W^X violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%5EX). Apps should load only the binary code that's embedded within an app's APK file.

Please note that what you are doing may also violate the terms of service of your desired app distribution channel.

Comment: Thanks, any how how to get it `embedded within an app's APK file` and execute it from there, I tried to ut it in `assets`, but understood it is not executable as well.

Comment: @HasanAYousef: You can compile native code into your app using the NDK.

Comment: I do not have the source code, just have the final binary, so want to run it!